# R recommendations while applying ggplot2 and plotly together to plot a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data frame having 3 columns namely index, Actual & Predicted (all column are numeric).
I am using 2 packages `plotly` & `ggplot2` for plotting index on x-axis & Actual and Predicted on y-axis.
 The command for plotting the graphs goes as follows-

```
plot<- ggplotly(ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = index))+ geom_line(aes(y=Predicted), colour= "blue")+ geom_line(aes(y=Actual), colour="red"))

plot
```

The R was giving the plot smoothly without any recommendations, but suddenly it started giving recommendations like,

**We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`**

So I tried installing `ggplot2` with devtools as given in the recommendations.

I am able to plot the graph but still I am getting the above recommendation.

What does that recommendation mean and what to do if i am getting the recommendation even after installing it with **devtools** ?

Comment: I had the same message before, but it was gone upon installing the development version.

Comment: There's no need to worry. `ggploty` developers want you to use their development version so they could fix bugs easier. Don't worry, nothing really happened.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly is R package for creating interactive web-based graphs via plotly's JavaScript graphing library, plotly.js. The plotly R libary contains the ggplotly function , which will convert ggplot2 figures into a Plotly object.

If you are still getting the recommendation even after installing it, it seems it was not properly installed. Please refer the below git hub link and code to do the same installation properly.

Try to via Hadley at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2

```
# install devtools
install.packages('devtools')

# install dependency of scales package
install.packages(c("RColorBrewer", "stringr", "dichromat", "munsell", "plyr", "colorspace"))

# Open devtools package
library(devtools)

# move to development mode
# scales and ggplot2 are installed in "~/R-dev" directory, so official version of ggplot2 are not removed.
dev_mode(TRUE)

install_github("hadley/scales", force=TRUE)
# main branch of development
install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
# (Optional) install_github("ggplot2", "kohske", "feature/new-guides-with-gtable")

# Exit dev mode
dev_mode(FALSE)

# load development version of ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
```